# AWS Cognito Login Flow Check

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

**BACKGROUND**: Obviously I don't know too much about cognito because I spent the last two hours attempting to authenticate my users with cognito and realized that they weren't authentication providers but rather organizers of credentials.Then I thought of an easier workaround instead of creating a entirely new backend for authenticating users and wanted to verify its viability.

**PLAN**: I was thinking that I would have users come onto my app and automatically be authenticated with Cognito as an unauthenticated user. Then I would use calls to AWS Lambda and Dynamodb (where my data is stored) and use either a facebookID, which would be obtained from a logged in Facebook user, or a username/password combo to do a basic check and authenticate a user.

Please let me know if any part of my **PLAN** isn't clear and I will elaborate.

**Question**: Please let me know if my **PLAN** is a safe way for me to authenticate users without making an intense backend solely dedicated to creating and storing accounts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Cognito Credentials to access Lambda and DynamoDB, that's exactly the use case Amazon Cognito is meant for.

If you want unauthenticated identities to later on migrate to authenticated with Facebook, note than once you link an identity with Facebook the user will always need to be authenticated to get credentials for that identity: you can't access it as unauthenticated again.

Comment: So I'm thinking that I have them unauthenticated initially. Then have unauthenticated users be permitted only TWO lambda methods such as login and signup. From there either use facebook or my custom developer as an authentication provider? If this would be the case, how would I register/login users in my lambda method with cognito?

Comment: Your Lambda function could use DynamoDB to store your users, and implement the developer-authenticated identities flow explained here: http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2FL1QAPDE0UAH/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-2-Developer-Authenticated-Ident